# while (1) loop with continue and break statements

Tags: java, loops, break, infinite, continue

I need help with a while(1) loop that contains a continue and break statement. It must count from numbers 1 to 20 and for every even number, it must output the values. I have to use a continue after my writeToPage statement and use a break statement when it reaches 20.
This is what I tested out but the file will not even load:

```
writeToPage("Program 4: Continue and Break");
writeToPage("");

while(1) {
    if (i % 2 == 0){
        writeToPage(+ i);
        continue;
    }
    if (i >= 20){
        break;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm putting them in the wrong place.

Comment: Try `while (true) ` maybe?

Comment: `the file will not even load` what do you mean ? Also the continue is useless here

Comment: the instructions say to use while(1) but I'm not sure how to make it work

Comment: Change this line `writeToPage(+ i)` to `writeToPage(++i)` and come back again

Comment: You canno't use `while(1)` in Java, that is not valid

Comment: When I try to load my code into the browser it will not load, it just keeps saying it's loading. It works fine when I take out these lines of code.

Comment: U need boolean value maybe 1=1?

Comment: I tried i ++ and it did not work.

Comment: You should consistently line up your brackets and indentation. Doing so will make it far easier to see where a block of code starts and stops.

Comment: Why don't you link to the assignment, so we can deduce for ourselves what is required. It sounds like your professor just wanted you to specify an _infinite_ loop, e.g. `while(true)`, `for(;;)`, or `while(1)` in languages where `0`==`false`

Comment: I'm not sure how to link here as I'm still new but these were the instructions:

Comment: // Program 4:
  // Write a while (1) loop (infinite loop) that counts
  // numbers from 1 to 20, for every even number
  // print out the values and use 'continue' after
  // the write statement
  //
  // When you reach the number past 20, break from the
  // loop using the break statement
  //

Comment: If the instructions say to use `while (1)`, then the instructions are not for Java, but maybe C++ or JavaScript. Please pay attention to what language you're learning and/or writing in (or find better learning material that actually fits the language you're using).

Comment: In c, ``while(1)`` is the idiom for an infinite loop. In java, the idiom is ``while(true)1`` because java doesn't allow you to use an int instead of a boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For infinite loop, you need to write `while(true)` instead of `while(1)`.
2. If `i % 2 != 0` is `true`, simply increment `i` by `1` and `continue`; otherwise, print the value of `i` and increment `i` by `1`.

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (i % 2 != 0) {
                i++;
                continue;
            } else {
                writeToPage(i);
                i++;
            }

            if (i >= 20) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    static void writeToPage(int i) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you!